# Why does C++ give a "can't find path" error?

Tags: c++, powershell, terminal, path, mingw

I'm simply trying to print out `Hello world`. I installed minGW, but the code simply won't work. It gives a "can't find path" error, but I have completed everything to download minGW, and the command prompt shows nothing wrong when I typed `cd desktop`. Additionally, I enabled theVSC to run on the terminal, but it won't work.

I am expecting the code to print `Hello world`, but this is what it prints out:

```
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\MinGW\binc\Users\Harold\Desktop\waffle\' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd "C:/MinGW/binc/Users/Harold/Desktop/waffle/" ; if ($?) { g++ test. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\MinGW\binc\U...Desktop\waffle\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: The issue is not c++ it's your shell.

Comment: `cd "C:/MinGW/binc/Users/Harold/Desktop/waffle/` seems to be wrong so your shell is correct in pointing out that you passed an invalid path.

Comment: Since you apparently are attempting to use VSCode and are not following the official VSCode instructions I recommend you start over and follow the proper instructions: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Looks like you used powershell and Unix style directory separators.

Comment: does the folder C:/MinGW/binc/Users/Harold/Desktop/waffle/ exist on your computer?